# TBX3 Protein structure and function

Tags: protein-structure

Is it possible for an anti-cancer monoclonal antibody to target the two repressor domains in the N and C terminal of the TBX3 protein ?

Comment: It is very unlikely that an antibody binds to two domains of a protein at the same time. If the two domains have a high structural similarity it might be possible that one TBX3 protein binds two identical antibodies. You could align the two domains and see if they have a common sequence stretch. If that's the case you could check if the stretch is unique, i.e. otherwise the antibody would bind to more than just RBX3.

Comment: Hypothetical questions have been asked here and we consider them on-topic if sufficient background and rationale is provided. Can you please elaborate your question? As it stands, it looks like a *primarily opinion-based* question and is likely to be put on-hold. Moreover, because of the lack of background, your question is also a bit unclear.